# OpenAI API Error: Resource not found - Text Summarization in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, azure, openai-api, summarization, azure-openai

Here is the text summarization function. I have valid azure openai API, endpoint through a valid subscription and I have mentioned them in the .env file correctly. I do feel the issue is in this url - `${endpoint}/v1/chat/completions`. Please provide any solution.

```
    const prompt = `Provide a summary of the text: ${data}`;
    const apiKey = process.env.AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY;
    const endpoint = process.env.AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT;
    const url = `${endpoint}/v1/chat/completions`;

    const response = await axios.post(
      url,
      {
        model: "gpt-35-turbo",
        prompt: prompt,
        temperature: 0.3,
        max_tokens: 250,
        top_p: 1,
        frequency_penalty: 0,
        presence_penalty: 0
      },
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${apiKey}`,
        },
      }
    );
    const summary = response.data.choices[0].text.trim();
    return summary;
```

I tried,

const url = `${endpoint}/v1/completions`;

const url = `${endpoint}/openai/deployments/MY_DEPLOYMENT_NAME/completions?api-version=2023-05-15`;

const url = `${endpoint}/openai/deployments/MY_DEPLOYMENT_NAME/completions?api-version=2023-05-15-preview`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have a valid subscription, valid Azure OpenAI API key and endpoint.

```
const { OpenAIClient, AzureKeyCredential } = require("@azure/openai");

const generateSummary = async (data) => {
  const messages = [
    { role: "user", content: `Provide a summary of the text: ${data}` },
  ];

  try {
    const client = new OpenAIClient(endpoint, new AzureKeyCredential(azureApiKey));
    const deploymentId = "<MY_DEPLOYMENT_NAME>";
    const result = await client.getChatCompletions(deploymentId, messages);

    for (const choice of result.choices) {
      const summary = choice.message.content;
      return summary;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("The sample encountered an error:", err);
  }
};
```